# How to get Audio embeddings using Hubert model

Tags: nlp, pytorch

Example code:

```
import torch
from transformers import Wav2Vec2Processor, HubertForCTC
from datasets import load_dataset

processor = Wav2Vec2Processor.from_pretrained("facebook/hubert-large-ls960-ft")
model = HubertForCTC.from_pretrained("facebook/hubert-large-ls960-ft")
input_values = processor('array from audio file., return_tensors="pt").input_values
```

How to get embeddings after this ? There is no last hidden state in the model .